# Why the test in web chat bot not responding

Tags: node.js, azure, webbot

Completed build the web bot app in `Microsoft Azure`. It runs fine in the bot emulator locally. But in the azure , in the beginning it doesn't respond to the question asked. Now it keeps me waiting for the bot to ready.

Issue is listed as:

> There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError

There was no option to update `QnAKnowledgebaseId`,`QnAAuthKey` and `QnAEndpointHostName` and hence I manually added those field.

When did I go wrong and how do I get it working in Azure?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to note:

- Please ensure you have updated the Messaging endpoint correctly as described in the picture below:

[image]

- Make sure you have updated the MS App ID and password correctly, also the QNAKnowledgeBaseID in the configuration section like below:

[image]

If still doesn't help , please connect application Insights to your bot in order to see the innerExceptions of this InternalServerError. With app insights you can see the Failed Requests the exceptions and the specific platform errors.

Hope it helps, feel free to tag me in your conversation and share the code repo , will help further.